# Why can't connect internet after replacing the moterboard?

Tags: networking, internet

My old pc use a H81M motherboard for 8 years,dual os--win10 and debian installed in it,today i buy a new M81H motherboard (same H81M board,different brand) and replace the old one.
Network structure: modem + router.
Reboot my pc ,enter into win10,it can connect internet as normal.
Reboot my pc ,enter into debian,it can't connect internet.

```
lspci |grep -i  Ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
lspci -v
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7c04000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168

sudo systemctl status wicd
#It is in good status.
lsmod |grep 816
r8168 
 
cat  /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

How to fix it?

```
sudo  dmesg |grep  8168
[    0.220354] pci 0000:01:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    1.225031] r8168: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.225284] r8168: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.226698] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.048.03-NAPI loaded
[    1.284376] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    1.286372] r8168  Copyright (C) 2020  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[    1.293220] r8168 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0

ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:f3:17:00:36:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: systemd logs of networking? dmesg?

Comment: Output of `ip a`? Could it be that your DHCP server ignores the new MAC address? Try setting a static address.

Comment: It may be necessary to use the other name in the config for some weird reason now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My network card was known as `enp1s0` instead of `eth0` or something else.

```
ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:f3:17:00:36:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I replace `eth0` with `enp1s0` in config file:

```
sudo vim  /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
```

Reboot and connect to internet successfully.